# Get more space in margin

Tags: margins, geometry

I'm trying to get my bottom margin to be smaller in a one-page document. I've tried using geometry, but even if I use

```
\usepackage[noheadfoot=true,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[noheadfoot=true,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=-15in]{geometry}
```

I still have a huge gap (at least an inch) at the bottom of the page. How do I get this space back so more text can fit on one page?

Comment: How come [this minimal document](https://pastebin.com/raw/6hfM2r43) proves you wrong? See [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXa3P.png) showing 2 pages, the first of which has text going right to the bottom. Can you provide some evidence in the form of a minimal document that replicates your issue?

Comment: have you specified the right page size for your physical page (a4paper or usletter)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that setting the `bottom` option to a negative length is a good idea. Rather, I'd set `bottom=1mm` (or some other very small positive length), while also specifying the `noheadfoot` option and setting `\pagestyle{empty}`.

[image]

The rectangle around the textblock is drawn because the `showframe` option is set.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[hmargin=1in,top=1in,bottom=1mm,noheadfoot,
            showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14] % plenty of filler text
\end{document}
```